# Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 | FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Administrator\StudioProjects\smart_online_store\android\app\build.gradle' line: 3
- What went wrong:
  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin']

> Failed to apply plugin 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assemble Debug failed with exit code 1